# Replacing an element in DOM with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to replace an element in my dom so it changes when my table row is updated, but without much success.
I tried :

```
$(this).closest("tr").find(".nameDom").text("new value");
```

But it didn't work for me.
I also tried a couple of variations to this code without a result.

I will appreciate any tips on that issue.

Here is a screenshot of my html structure :

[image: Capture problem]

Here is the whole jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#saveBtn").on("click",function() {

        var productId = $("#productIdModal").val();
        var productName = $("#productNameModal").val();
        var productBrand = $("#productBrandModal").val();
        var productPrice = $("#productPriceModal").val();

        var jUpdatedProduct = {};
        jUpdatedProduct.id = productId;
        jUpdatedProduct.name = productName;
        jUpdatedProduct.brand = productBrand;
        jUpdatedProduct.price = productPrice;

        console.log(JSON.stringify(jUpdatedProduct));
        // console.log( jQuery.isEmptyObject(jUpdatedProduct));

        $(this).closest("tr").find(".nameDom").text("new val");
        $(this).closest("tr").find(".brandDom").text("new val");
        $(this).closest("tr").find(".priceDom").text("new val");

        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "GET",
            dataType : 'json',
            async: false,
            url: 'edit-product.php',
            data: { data: JSON.stringify(jUpdatedProduct) },
            success: function () {console.log("Thanks!"); },
            failure: function() {console.log("Error!");}
        });
    });
});
```

And here is the code for the modal, to which the `saveBtn` belongs :

```
<div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="productId" class="form-control" id="productIdModal" readonly>
      </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="productNameModal" class="form-control" id="productNameModal" placeholder="Product Name">
      </div>
       <div class="form-group">
          <input type="productBrandModal" class="form-control" id="productBrandModal" placeholder="Brand">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="productPriceModal" placeholder="Price">
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Show the HTML, may be you need `.val('new value')` and what's __this__ refers to?

Comment: Show your html and js code, one single line may not be enough.

Comment: I just uploaded a screenshot in my question.

Comment: `$(this).closest("tr").find(".nameDom").val("new value");`

Comment: please show your complete jquery code and the event you are listening to for table changes.

Comment: do you want this at doc ready ?

Comment: The markup here is relevant, but we also need the actual code. It would be even better if you can put it in a jsFiddle or similar to show us what's going on.

Comment: I am sorry, i just updated the question with the whole jQuery!

Comment: And where is the save button?

Comment: Should have mentioned this in your other post but if you have multiple buttons they should either have unique id's or just use a class. Referencing multiple elements with the same id can have unintended consequences (it's undefined behavior as the spec states that Id's should be unique to the document).

Comment: can you please post your HTML also, it would be easy to solve your issue.. Thanks

Comment: The save button is part of a bootstrap modal, so it should be just one.

Comment: If you add a `console.log("tr", $(this).closest("tr"))` to your click event what element gets highlighted? Can you then add the find as well? You can also set breakpoints in your js to see where the code hits and the state of your variables.

Comment: @scrappedcola [prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: button#saveBtn.btn.btn-success] . Does this answer your question?

Comment: Can create a fiddle in order to explain your question in a better way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace an DOM element in place with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845231/how-to-replace-an-dom-element-in-place-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `this` which is linking to the event `click` of the save button and not to the table. That is why you are not able to select correct element and thus update its value.

Try the following code below(I am assuming you only have 1 html table in your current page, if not you need to add the id of that table in below code selector) :

```
//Debug what element is getting selected in jquery first by using console commands 
console.info($(this) );
console.info('table');

$('table').closest("tr").find(".nameDom").text("new val");
$('table').closest("tr").find(".brandDom").text("new val");
$('table').closest("tr").find(".priceDom").text("new val");
```

You should replace these existing lines with the above code :

```
$(this).closest("tr").find(".nameDom").text("new val");
$(this).closest("tr").find(".brandDom").text("new val");
$(this).closest("tr").find(".priceDom").text("new val");
```

Comment: @Robert Please check the answer if this helped.

Comment: $('lblEditDeleteProducts').closest("tr").find(".nameDom").text("new val"); - I  tried this, which didn't work. But this could be my incompetence.

Comment: You forgot to add # for id `$('#lblEditDeleteProducts').closest("tr").find(".nameDom").te‌​xt("new val");`

Comment: always do a `console.info($('#lblEditDeleteProducts') )` or `console.log($('#lblEditDeleteProducts') )` to check if your jquery selector is  selecting the correct element.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but still doesnt work. Here is the result of the console.log  :  [tbody#lblEditDeleteProducts, context: document, selector: "#lblEditDeleteProducts"] This looks like the correct element for me.

Comment: You should do a `console.info($('#lblEditDeleteProducts').closest("tr").find(".nameDom") );` and check if you were able to select the desired element. 

Also try this code `$('#lblEditDeleteProducts').closest("tr .nameDom").html("new val");`

Comment: @RobertRoss `.closest` will not work as it traverses up the dom level from the current selected element. Try `.find`

This should work 
$('#lblEditDeleteProducts').find("tr .nameDom").text("new val");